# How To Setup Relationship between two same domain URL's

Tags: html, wordpress, search-engine, relation, googlebot

Hope All are doing well, I have a question also a doubt. Can we setup a relationship between the two URLs?

For Example, I have one [voiceover](https://wavel.ai/) page and i have created the use case for these voiceover services (for example using voiceover you can create [video ads](https://wavel.ai/use-case/video-ads/) ) Now Want to tell google bot that use case url have a relationship with voiceover page.

Can I use the rel attribute `<a rel="follow" href="https://wavel.ai/use-case/video-ads/">video ads</a>` on the use case pages to tell Google Bots about the relationship between two pages?

Need the relation idea between two pages! If I am correct as per the above practice then confirm me I am going well. if not then let me know how can i do this practice SEO.